# What permissions do i need to read users email folder using Graph Api?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am logged in as user1@acme.com in Graph Explorer. I am trying to read the email folder structure and contents of a generic email where we send documents to . The email is storage@acme.com. Both emails are under the same tenant/organization in Azure.

So if im logged in as  user1@acme.com , i send the command

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/storage@acme.com/mailFolders

It seems to give an error: "Forbidden - 403 - 226ms. You need to consent to the 
permissions on the Modify permissions (Preview) tab"
```

Which permission do i need to give ?

Answer (score 0):

As the message already stated, if you're using the MS Graph Explorer then there's a tab called "Modify permissions (preview)" which then displays all required permissions and also offers an option to consent to them.

Keep in mind that this is only a test environment. You still have to consent these permissions in your app later.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: I have added the permissions from Graph Explorer , but am getting access denied error. So if i  have 2 users lets say acmeuser@contoso.com , storage@acme.com . Every email that storage@acme.com gets acmeuser@contoso.com should get , that requires a shared email access. Do i need to set up anything in Azure to give acmeuser@contoso.com access to storage@acme.com  ?

Comment: Could be some configuration problem for your app registration, sometimes app-permissions aren't enough or not available and you need delegated ones. Take a look [here](https://www.azure365pro.com/access-specific-office-365-mailbox-using-microsoft-graph/) for some more help.